# How to create a database model with multiple products in one order

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm setting up a model of an SQL database that keeps track of an order with multiple products that have a certain quantity.

The table has to have a key value that is specific for that order and never repeats anywhere else in the table.

I'm thinking of making a row that has an orderID as key value, then an Order tab that has the productID and quantity like this "ProductID-Quantity" so that it can be placed in one cell. The tricky part is taking multiple different products in this row. It can be done inserting all the products with their quantities in one cell like this:

```
"1100-3, 1500-1, 1600-8"
```

So this is one cell with three products ordered 3, 1 and 8 times. Reading it in in PHP seperating them with a comma and a dash.

Is there any way to do this more effectively?

Comment: Put each data in a separate field instead of combining them. orderid,productid. So if there is an order with 3 times the same product, you will have 3 records(quantity)

Comment: but then i no longer have a unique key value, then you get 1 row of productID 1 with one product and another row with productID 1 with another  product, so then you're just splitting up the same problem.

Comment: Your unique key is the orderid. It can be an incremental value.

Comment: yeah but then one customer has mutliple order id's for the same order, i must be able to print out one's order one a single unique orderID (including every product ordered in said order)

Comment: No! You will have customerid, orderid, productid

Comment: i'm sorry i still don't fully see it, can you give me an example for ordering 2 white caps and 3 black ones, with customer id 10 or something
(i still don't see how one could link different orderID's to one customerID)

Comment: fields = Customerid, orderid, productid,quantity  
data(first item)= 10,100,1234,2  
data(Second item) = 10,100,4567,3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a "many to many" relationship. One order can hold many products but one product can be part of many rows as well.

For this you can create a table `orders` (in which additional info may be stored, eg. the userid it belongs to) and have your `products` table as well.

Now you connect them via something like this

```
CREATE TABLE order_products (
    orderid INT NOT NULL,
    productid INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (orderid, productid),
    FOREIGN KEY (orderid) REFERENCES orders (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES products (id)
);
```

To select get all rows with their products, simply use a [`JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join).

Comment: so you have a primary key of the orderID and the productID combined?

Comment: @WoutKooijman Yes, this way each order can have only one entry for one product (with a variable quantity)